# Issues with using recursion in the task

Tags: system-verilog

Please help understand one issue that I am facing when using recursion my task.
So there is a task which should keep track on 2 signals  enable and ddr_clk. They are asynchronous signals and enable can appear before ddr_clk posedge. In such case the task should wait for enable to come high after which @(posedge itf.ddr_clk) to happen, for write to be done.
To implement this I am using recursion in the task:

```
task automatic write();
    $display ("%t:\tdriver: write function", $time);
    if ( itf.enable == 1 ) begin
        $display ("%t:\tdriver-write: ->writing in DUT: assiging wdata and waiting for ddr_clk posedge...", $time);
        itf.wdata = req.data_wfifo_data; // assign and wait for clk posedge
        fork
            begin : wait_clock;
            @ (posedge itf.ddr_clk) 
                $display ("%t:\tdriver-write: Got ddr_clk posedge, considering write done", $time);
            end

            @(itf.enable) // In case when enable goes to low before posedge
            begin
                $display ("%t:\tdriver-write: enable changed, re-calling write", $time);
                disable wait_clock;
                write;
            end
        join_any
    end else 
    begin
        $display ("%t:\tdriver-write-enable: waiting for enable...", $time);
         @(itf.enable)
          write;
    end
    $display ("%t:\tdriver: END write function", $time);

endtask
```

And this is what simulation result gives:

```
65490750.0 ps:  driver: write function
65490750.0 ps:  driver-write: ->writing in DUT: assiging data_wfifo_data and waiting for ddr_clk posedge...
65490850.0 ps:  driver-write: enable changed, re-calling write
65490850.0 ps:  driver: write function
65490850.0 ps:  driver-write-enable: waiting for enable...
65490850.0 ps:  driver-write: enable changed, re-calling write
65490850.0 ps:  driver: write function
65490850.0 ps:  driver-write-enable: waiting for enable...
65490850.0 ps:  driver: END write function
65490850.0 ps: Driver: END Calling write task to write in DUT
```

At the same simulation time the task is being called multiple times and then exitting.

Please help understand the behavioral.
I have impression that “disable wait_clock” statement is not working there…

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand the requirements. Perhaps you could draw some waveforms?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you haven't shown us the complete log of activity. There must have been earlier $display statements from this task. Also, are you sure data is stable while enable is true?

The problem is every time you call `write()` with enable `true`, if you get a `@(posedge itf.ddr_clk)` *before* `enable` goes low, you are left with a dangling process. Then when `enable` does go low, they are all triggered at once. You could put a `disable fork` after the `join_any`.

I think using recursion here make things more complicated. I would use a loop instead

```
task write;
  fork
    forever begin
              wait(itf.enable);
              itf.wdata = req.data_wfifo_data;
              wait(!itf.enable);  // @(itf.enable or req.data_wfifo_data) -- if really level sensitive 
            end
    @(posedge itf.ddr_clk iff itf.enable);
  join_any
  disable fork;
endtask
```

Comment: Thanks, I put disable fork after join_any and it is working
Nice idea with iff usage, it never came to my mind

Answer (score 0):

In the fork and join_any block the  second block  (its.enable ) gets executed at 65490850.0 it disable the wait_clock block and the calls write (2).

This results in two flow .

1. the write(2) is called a second time in recursion . 
   The second task will wait and even complete at a later time or further call write recursively.
2. In the write(1) instance the wait_clock block is disabled and the fork join_any now completes execution. 
   As its join_any the disabled block triggers the completion of the join_any. The codes goes through skipping the else and displays the “END write function” and return to the main calling function in the driver.

   Then the main function which called the write will show the display “ END calling write task to write in DUT” .

One solution

added count to see how many times the recursion is called . It also aids debug.
Also it is used to start waiting for a trigger for the first execution ( of write ) . Anytime the wait_clock is done it generates the trigger.
You can instantiate the trigger in the structure of your preference.

```
task automatic write(int count );
    $display ("%t:\tdriver: write function , count %d", $time,count);
    if ( itf.enable == 1 ) begin
        $display ("%t:\tdriver-write: ->writing in DUT: assiging wdata and waiting for ddr_clk posedge... count %d", $time,count);
        itf.wdata = req.data_wfifo_data; // assign and wait for clk posedge
        fork
            begin : wait_clock;
            @ (posedge itf.ddr_clk)
                $display ("%t:\tdriver-write: Got ddr_clk posedge, considering write done count %d", $time,count);
                ->itf.done;
                //disable wait_enable;
            end

           //begin : wait_enable
            @(itf.enable) // In case when enable goes to low before posedge
            begin
                $display ("%t:\tdriver-write: enable changed, re-calling write count %d", $time,count);
                disable wait_clock;
                write(count+1);
            end
           //end
        join_any
    end else
    begin
        $display ("%t:\tdriver-write-enable: waiting for enable...count %d", $time,count);
         @(itf.enable)
          write(count+1);
    end
    if ( count == 0 ) wait (itf.done.triggered);
    $display ("%t:\tdriver: END write function , count %d", $time,count);

end task
```

But a recursive function is difficult to keep track of and debug. In this case a loop based function MIGHT do just as good. 
The recursion has another potential issues, as disabling the wait_clock block will  cause all the wait_clock blocks in all the recursive function to be disabled. Not sure it will cause an issue but something to keep a lookout for.

Based on limited data/understating of the protocol , a loop based function is presented below.
The code is trying to mimic the code above but can be further simplified or even modified easily for protocol related fixes.

```
task automatic write_non_recursive ();
int done,got_clock,got_enable ;
    done = 0 ;
    $display ("%t:\tdriver: write function , ", $time);
    while ( done == 0 )
    begin
        if ( itf.enable == 1 ) begin
            $display ("%t:\tdriver-write: ->writing in DUT: assiging wdata and waiting for ddr_clk posedge... ", $time);
            itf.wdata = req.data_wfifo_data; // assign and wait for clk posedge   
        end
        got_clock = 0 ;
        fork
            begin //using got clock to check edge
                @ (posedge itf.ddr_clk) ; got_clock = 1;
            end
            @(itf.enable) ;
        join_any
        //if ( itf.ddr_clk == 1 && itf.enable == 1 ) - if we were looking onyl into clock
        if ( got_clock == 1 && itf.enable == 1 )
        begin
                $display ("%t:\tdriver-write: Got ddr_clk posedge, considering write done ", $time);
                done = 1;
        end
        else if ( itf.enable == 0 ) // en = 0 , clk = 1 or en = 0 , clk = 0 ;
        begin
                $display ("%t:\tdriver-write: enable changed, re-calling write ", $time);
                @(itf.enable) ; // wait for the next edge
        end
        else  // en = 1 , clk = 0 ;
                $display ("%t:\tdriver-write-enable: waiting for enable...", $time);
        got_clock = 0; //reset and look for edge again
    end
    $display ("%t:\tdriver: END write function , ", $time);

end task
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining what is going in the iteration, now I can understand it